# Asynchronous Multiple Tasks in C# windows service ( with two different await times )

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, polling

```
public Class Config
{
  public string Name;
  public string Interval;
}
```

I have List Of Tasks Coming from database

```
List<Config> configList = new List<Config>();
```

Every task coming from database will have Name and Interval

for example say i have two items in list with following data

1. Name is X and Interval is 2 mins
2. Name is Y and Interval is 4 mins

Now I need a windows service, where i want to run or execute
Task X for every 2 mins,
Tasks Y for every 4 mins in asynchronous manner.

I know that, we have to use Polling.

I managed to poll database for every 'XXX' mins (eg 5 mins) by googling out but am unable to run two tasks with two different intervals in asynchronous manner.

for every poll, i have to run two tasks and for 1st task i need to wait for 2 mins before the next poll begins and for 2nd task i need to wait for 4 mins before the next poll begins and that too in asynchronous manner. please help.

Update -1

Am using the following code to poll database for every 2 mins

```
private Task _proccessTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _proccessTask= Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token));
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        _proccessTask.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exeption
    }
}
public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            ProccessTaskX();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
   //able to poll database for every 2 mins in async manner if i have 1 task

      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), token);

    }
}
```

Now I want to Run or execute list of 2 tasks with two different intervals
i.e TaskX for every 2 mins and TaskY for every 4 mins and both tasks should run in asynchronous manner, thanks in advance, please help.

Comment: it's unclear (to me) if Your problem is of algorithmic nature (answer to "what should I do to get what I want?", which can be given in pseudocode) or technical ("how do I start a procedure in c# in a separate thread?")

Comment: Did you try two times?

Comment: @TymurGubayev thanks for the reply, how can i achieve the above scenario by using Task Parallel programing or (threads)....?

Comment: @susheel the code in "Update-1" is (or should be) implementation of a class. Just add some `public int interval_minutes` and use it instead of the `2` in the `Task.Delay`. The next step would be to have different objects of that class for different `Config`s. Also consider using another property to hold a delegate of the task's internal function -- instead of `ProcessTaskX()`.

Comment: thanks @TymurGubayev :-)